# Why pandas has its own datetime object Timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

The documentation of pandas.Timestamp states a concept well-known to every pandas user:

> Timestamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is interchangeable with it in most cases.

But I don't understand why are pandas.Timestamps needed at all.
Why is, or was, it useful to have a different object than python's Datetime? Wouldn't it be cleaner to simply build pandas.DatetimeIndex out of Datetimes?

Comment: It's probably a thin wrapper with some extra methods useful for `pandas` users. Did you compare the APIs of the two classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through Pandas documentation for the details:

> `"pandas.Timestamp"` is a replacement for python datetime.datetime for
>   Padas usage.
>
> Timestamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is
>   interchangeable with it in most cases. It’s the type used for the
>   entries that make up a DatetimeIndex, and other timeseries oriented
>   data structures in pandas.
>
> **Notes**
>
> There are essentially three calling conventions for the constructor.
>   The primary form accepts four parameters. They can be passed by
>   position or keyword.
>
> The other two forms mimic the parameters from datetime.datetime. They
>   can be passed by either position or keyword, but not both mixed
>   together.
>
> Timedeltas are differences in times, expressed in difference units,
>   e.g. days, hours, minutes, seconds. They can be both positive and
>   negative.
>
> Timedelta is a subclass of `datetime.timedelta`, and behaves in a
>   similar manner, **but allows compatibility with np.timedelta64 types
>   as well as a host of custom representation, parsing, and attributes**.

I would say as pandas works better with Time Series data hence its been a kind of warper on the original built-in datetime module.

> The weaknesses of Python's datetime format inspired the NumPy team to
>   add a set of native time series data type to NumPy. The datetime64
>   dtype encodes dates as 64-bit integers, and thus allows arrays of
>   dates to be represented very compactly.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed the page I cited, but it doesn't tell us "why" do we have a pandas.Timestamp.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano, i believe you can get some references [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.11-working-with-time-series.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. +1 and accepted :)

Comment: Glad to see that's useful.